# How to exclude unpacked dependencies from third-party jars?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, logging, log4j2, slf4j

I have a spring boot application `MyApp`. `MyApp` is having a dependency on a third-party library `ThirdParty` which is also a spring-boot application. This `ThirdParty` library is a fat jar where all the internal dependencies are included as unpacked class files instead of libraries.

One of the internal dependencies within that `ThirdParty` jar is `slf4j` and `reload4j` which is a logging framework. `MyApp` is using `slf4j` and `log4j2`.

Now whenever I try to run `MyApp`, it is giving me warning saying multiple bindings for slf4j found. I am getting `LoggingException` as well saying: `log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j`. I suspect it is because of these different logging libraries used within `MyApp` and `ThirdParty` jar.

I tried to exclude the dependencies from `ThirdParty` jar in my `pom.xml` but it is somehow not working as I keep on getting the same warning and error. I also scanned the `MyApp` application using `dependency:tree` and `effective-pom` but I do not see any presence of those jars in error.

I suspect the exclusions are not working because of unpacked classes within `ThirdParty`. Could someone please let me know how to exclude the unpacked classes from third-party jars?

Comment: The ThirdParty jar is the issue. First is that the result of a spring boot build? If yes you can't even use that because spring boot jar's are not usual jar's...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes this jar is outcome of ```spring-boot-maven-plugin```. It is a fat jar. Why do you think we cannot use it as a dependency?

Comment: I don't think you can't use. I know 100% sure that is not usuable as a usual dependency because a spring boot fat jar has a complete different internal structure (at the root only the bootstrap classes for Spring Boot are in there and in BOOT-INF/lib/ the containing jars are packaged etc.)  than a usual jar file that makes it unusable as a dependency. If you like to use it you have to change your packaging (or make a supplemental execution for separate packaging (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: Ohk. Understood. Thanks for highlighting this, it will come in handy for me in the future. Coming back to original question, for maven built libs, is there any way to exclude unpacked jars?

Comment: The excluding is based on the artifacts which means groupId/artifactId/(version).. but not on the package level.. and furthermore you usually consume unpacked jars.. that also sounds a bit strange because you consume on jar level...For your example with the spring boot part you have to separate into at least two modules one with the `@SpringBootApplication` part and the other module what you like to reuse.. (multi module setup for Spring Boot offers exactl such thing)...